# gVim updates the title text field when the window is made narrower - can I stop this handy behavior?

Tags: windows, vim, gvim

Depending on the width of the GUI window, gVim 9.0 on Windows 10 (maybe Win 11 as well) would decide to be creative with the title text of the window, and show any of the following when I review my daily note in Vimwiki:

```
<md GVIM2 n
<house/2022-10-29.md GVIM2 n 
~/Dropbox/Wiki/Warehouse/2022-10-29.md GVIM3 n (This is the full title text)
```

Here is another example, where the same help-file is loaded in two gVim windows of different width - the title-text on the left is abbreviated because of window-resizing.
[image]

---

**Question:** Am I missing a simple setting to stop this intuitive behavior? I use Autohotkey that group gVim windows based on snippets in its title text, and prefer to keep the intended "full" title-string in gVim's title bar.

Comment: See `:help 'titlelen'`.

Comment: @romainl Nailed it! Thanks a lot! `set titlelen=30000` gets the job done!

Comment: You should post the solution and accept it.

Comment: Sounds good. Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@romainl](https://superuser.com/users/60075/romainl) suggested, to start looking for a solution to this, one should check out `:help 'titlelen'`.

Then, the solution is to include the following one-liner in `.vimrc`:

```
set titlelen=0
```

Per the documentation, setting `0` would show the full path in the window title field.

> When 'titlelen' is zero the full path is used.  Otherwise,
> values from 1 to 30000 percent can be used.